# How to retrieve the corresponding values from XML file in vb.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, oracle

I need to Retrieve the values from a XML file i have seen many example but none of them is like the XML I have.
My XML look like this .

```
  <title>TOSSICOLOGIA D'ABUSO</title>
                <component>
                    <section>
                        <code code="31011" codeSystemName="Codifica Interna Laboratorio" displayName="Etanolo (urine)">
                            <!--TRASCODIFICA ANALISI NON DISPONIBILE-->
                        </code>
                        <text>
                            <paragraph>
                            </paragraph>
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Esame</th>
                                        <th>Esito</th>
                                        <th>Abnormal Flag</th>
                                        <th>Unita di misura</th>
                                        <th>Range di riferimento</th>
                                        <th>Metodo</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Etanolo (urine)</td>
                                        <td>&lt; 0,01 g/l</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>fino a 0,35</td>
                                        <td />
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <footnote></footnote>
                            <paragraph>
                            </paragraph>
                            <!--Inizio Microbiologia sezione humane readable-->
                            <!--Fine   Microbiologia sezione humane readable-->
                        </text>
                        <entry typeCode="DRIV">
                            <!-- INIZIO MONO RISULTATO -->
                            <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
                                <code code="31011" codeSystemName="Codifica Interna Laboratorio" displayName="Etanolo (urine)">
                                    <!--TRASCODIFICA ANALISI NON DISPONIBILE-->
                                </code>
                                <statusCode code="completed" />
                                <!--(INIZIO) GESTIONE MICROBIOLOGIA MONO RISULTATO -->
                                <!--(FINE) GESTIONE MICROBIOLOGIA MONO RISULTATO -->
                                <entryRelationship typeCode="COMP">
                                    <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                                        <code code="31011" codeSystemName="Codifica Interna Laboratorio" displayName="Etanolo (urine)">
                                            <!--TRASCODIFICA RISULTATI NON DISPONIBILE-->
                                            <!--ANL_COMPLETED-->
                                        </code>
                                        <statusCode code="completed" />
                                        <effectiveTime value="20170216131204" />
                                        <value xsi:type="ST">&lt; 0,01 g/l</value>
                                        <!---->
                                        <referenceRange typeCode="REFV">
                                            <observationRange classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN.CRT">
                                                <value xsi:type="IVL_PQ">
                                                    <low value="0.00" />
                                                    <high value="0.35" />
                                                </value>
                                                <interpretationCode code="N" />
                                            </observationRange>
                                        </referenceRange>
                                        <referenceRange typeCode="REFV">
                                            <observationRange classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN.CRT">
                                                <value xsi:type="ST">fino a 0,35</value>
                                                <interpretationCode code="N" />
                                            </observationRange>
                                        </referenceRange>
                                    </observation>
                                </entryRelationship>
                                <!-- VAL USED -->
                            </act>
                            <!-- FINE MONO RISULTATO -->
                        </entry>
                    </section>
                </component>
                <component>
                    <section>
                        <code code="32000" codeSystemName="Codifica Interna Laboratorio" displayName="Creatininuria">
                            <!--TRASCODIFICA ANALISI NON DISPONIBILE-->
                        </code>
                        <text>
                            <paragraph>
                                <content ID="ANLNOTE---2-2">Prova autenticità campione droghe</content>
                            </paragraph>
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Esame</th>
                                        <th>Esito</th>
                                        <th>Abnormal Flag</th>
                                        <th>Unita di misura</th>
                                        <th>Range di riferimento</th>
                                        <th>Metodo</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Creatininuria</td>
                                        <td>193.0</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>mg/dL</td>
                                        <td>fino a 20: campione non idoneo
                                            (non utilizzabile ai fini medico legali)
                                            20 - 40: campione dubbio
                                            sup. a 40: campione idoneo
                                        </td>
                                        <td />
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <footnote></footnote>
                            <paragraph>
                            </paragraph>
                            <!--Inizio Microbiologia sezione humane readable-->
                            <!--Fine   Microbiologia sezione humane readable-->
                        </text>
                        <entry typeCode="DRIV">
                            <!-- INIZIO MONO RISULTATO -->
                            <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
                                <code code="32000" codeSystemName="Codifica Interna Laboratorio" displayName="Creatininuria">
                                    <!--TRASCODIFICA ANALISI NON DISPONIBILE-->
                                </code>
                                <statusCode code="completed" />
                                <!--(INIZIO) GESTIONE MICROBIOLOGIA MONO RISULTATO -->
                                <!--(FINE) GESTIONE MICROBIOLOGIA MONO RISULTATO -->
                                <entryRelationship typeCode="SUBJ">
                                    <act classCode="ACT" moodCode="EVN">
                                        <code code="48767-8" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Annotation Comment" />
                                        <text>
                                            <reference value="ANLNOTE---2-2" />
                                        </text>
                                    </act>
                                </entryRelationship>
                                <entryRelationship typeCode="COMP">
                                    <observation classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN">
                                        <code code="32000" codeSystemName="Codifica Interna Laboratorio" displayName="Creatininuria">
                                            <!--TRASCODIFICA RISULTATI NON DISPONIBILE-->
                                            <!--ANL_COMPLETED-->
                                        </code>
                                        <statusCode code="completed" />
                                        <effectiveTime value="20170216121035" />
                                        <value xsi:type="PQ" value="193.0" unit="mg/dL" />
                                        <referenceRange typeCode="REFV">
                                            <observationRange classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN.CRT">
                                                <value xsi:type="IVL_PQ">
                                                    <low value="40.0" unit="mg/dL" />
                                                    <high value="99999.0" unit="mg/dL" />
                                                </value>
                                                <interpretationCode code="N" />
                                            </observationRange>
                                        </referenceRange>
                                        <referenceRange typeCode="REFV">
                                            <observationRange classCode="OBS" moodCode="EVN.CRT">
                                                <value xsi:type="ST">fino a 20: campione non idoneo
                                                    (non utilizzabile ai fini medico legali)
                                                    20 - 40: campione dubbio
                                                    sup. a 40: campione idoneo
                                                </value>
                                                <interpretationCode code="N" />
                                            </observationRange>
                                        </referenceRange>
                                    </observation>
                                </entryRelationship>
                                <!-- VAL USED -->
                            </act>
                            <!-- FINE MONO RISULTATO -->
                        </entry>
                    </section>
```

As you can see is like a html table.I have create a table in database with those 
 FIELDS name, and i need to put the  values of the fields in database.

But first of all i need a way how to get the VALUES using visual basic and later on to see how to put the value on db.
So this is the image that tell the value i need are under tag ,,td'' at the XML.
But the table ate db should look like this....  the value of the part of XML is the first in the second table.

[image]

For this part of the code i can use

```
 Dim path As String = "C:\Users\ShkelzenTarja\projekt\CDR_v3_1\CDR\test2.xml"    ' "put path to xml file here"
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = XElement.Load("C:\Users\ShkelzenTarja\projekt\CDR_v3_1\CDR\test2.xml")
    Dim sectn As XElement = (From el In xe...<code> Select el Take 1).FirstOrDefault

    If sectn IsNot Nothing Then 'did we get a code
        'yes
        sectn = sectn.Parent 'the section
        '
    End If
    If sectn IsNot Nothing Then 'did we get a section
        'yes
        For Each tr As XElement In sectn...<table>.<tbody>.<tr>
            For Each td As XElement In tr.<td>
                Debug.WriteLine(td.Value)
            Next
        Next

    End If
```

but i have some question :

1- the diff of path and xe = XElement.Load

2- Select el Take 1).FirstOrDefault  ... how can i change this in order to get all the values the document has and not only the first one .

3- should i use the same sintax if my xml has two title because in fact it has as you can see at the photo .
Thank you for your help @dbasnett

MY all Xml is here :
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5OsUU9OkwHrSjc1YlBDcDRlOWdudURRQXR0cEc5RTUyeWV3)

Comment: Which values do you like to get from the XML? And how does your table look like?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i just edit my post is clear now?

Comment: @DWRoelands do you have any idea

Comment: No, first of all (and again) provide the table as **formatted text** not as an image. How is the first table "droghe d'abuso screening" related to the XML?

Comment: the values that are at the table show are the value at xml... and  those are the value i need to get

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the table dispaly is the one in db that will keep the value but the colums and the values are in xml.

Comment: Do you like to store the entire XML in the database or just some field values?

Comment: just the values that xml has for xml for  Creatininuria we have 5 colums <tr>
                                            <th>Esame</th>
                                            <th>Esito</th>
                                            <th>Abnormal Flag</th>
                                            <th>Unita di misura</th>
                                            <th>Range di riferimento</th>
                                            <th>Metodo</th>
                                        </tr>    and the values are Creatininuria,193.0,-,mg/dL, etc.

Comment: the values that are in td tag

Comment: I dont know if i should  store the entire XML in the database .. but for the momemnt i need only to take those value i told and insert them in a table in db.

Comment: Ok, we are not here to write your software. Split your task into two steps. Step one is to parse the XML values. Write a program which will at the end have something like `Debug.WriteLine("Esame => {0}", Esame)` printing `Esame => Etanolo (urine)`. After you finished that, go to second step and insert these values into database, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361189/vb-net-oracle-insert-with-parameters-ora-00936-missing-expression or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885571/missing-expression-in-insert-query-using-vb-net-with-oracle-parameter

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i just need an example i dont need yopu to do my work,,, hlp is what i need

Comment: Tell us at least where you stuck. At step one or step two? For step two you see examples in linked questions

Comment: at step one i am stuck

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit  can you help now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution

Private Sub GetContinents()

```
    Const FILENAME As String = "C:\Users\ShkelzenTarja\projekt\CDR_v3_1\CDR\test.xml"

    Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()

    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment

    Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME, settings)


    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Display Name", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Code", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Esame", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Esito", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Abnormal Flag", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Unita Di Misura", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Range Di Riferimento", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Metoda", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Low", GetType(Decimal))
    dt.Columns.Add("High", GetType(Decimal))
    dt.Columns.Add("Time", GetType(DateTime))


    Dim uri = "urn:hl7-org:v3"

    While (Not reader.EOF)

        If reader.Name <> "section" Then

            reader.ReadToFollowing("section", uri)
        End If
        If Not reader.EOF Then

            Dim section As XElement = CType(XElement.ReadFrom(reader), XElement)

            Dim xCode As XElement = section.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "code").FirstOrDefault()
            Dim displayName As String = CType(xCode.Attribute("displayName"), String)

            For Each xComponent As XElement In section.Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "component")
                Dim xEsame As XElement = xComponent.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "code").FirstOrDefault()
                Dim code As String = CType(xEsame.Attribute("code"), String)

                Dim xBody As XElement = xComponent.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "tbody").FirstOrDefault()
                Dim data As New List(Of String)
                data.AddRange({displayName, code})
                data.AddRange(xBody.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "td").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)))

                Dim entry As XElement = section.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "entry").FirstOrDefault()

                Dim low As XElement = entry.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "low").FirstOrDefault()
                If low Is Nothing Then
                    data.Add(Nothing)
                Else
                    data.Add(Decimal.Parse(CType(low.Attribute("value"), String)))
                End If
                Dim high As XElement = entry.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "high").FirstOrDefault()
                If high Is Nothing Then
                    data.Add(Nothing)
                Else
                    data.Add(Decimal.Parse(CType(high.Attribute("value"), String)))
                End If

                Dim effectiveTime As XElement = entry.Descendants().Where(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "effectiveTime").FirstOrDefault()
                Dim dateStr As String = CType(effectiveTime.Attribute("value"), String)
                data.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

                'For i = 0 To data.Count - 1
                Insert_CDA_Data(data)
                    '    i = i + 11
                    'Next
                    'dt.Rows.Add(data.ToArray())
                    'Debug.WriteLine(dt)

                Next xComponent

        End If
    End While

End Sub

Private Function Insert_CDA_Data(ByVal data As List(Of String))
    Dim esito As Boolean = True

    Try
        Using scope As New TransactionScope()

            operations.INSERT_CDA(ucDataCapture(data))
            scope.Complete()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        esito = False
        Dim log As New Log
        log.writeLog("Cda", ex)
    End Try

    Return esito
End Function

Private Function ucDataCapture(ByVal data As List(Of String)) As CDA

    Dim CDA_D As New CDA

    Try
        CDA_D.codeProperty = data(1)
        CDA_D.nameProperty = data(0)
        CDA_D.esameProperty = data(2)
        CDA_D.esitoProperty = data(3)
        CDA_D.abnormalFlagProperty = data(4)
        CDA_D.unitaDiMisuraProperty = data(5)
        CDA_D.rangeDiRiferimentoProperty = data(6)
        CDA_D.metodaProperty = data(7)
        If data(8) IsNot Nothing Then
            CDA_D.lowProperty = data(8)
        Else
            CDA_D.lowProperty = ""
        End If
        If data(9) IsNot Nothing Then
            CDA_D.highProperty = data(9)
        Else
            CDA_D.highProperty = ""
        End If

        CDA_D.effectiveTimeProperty = data(10)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim log As New Log
        log.writeLog("Cda ", ex)
    End Try
    Return CDA_D

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML example was not formatted correctly.  This might give you an idea

For the production code use

```
    Dim path As String = "put path to xml file here"
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = XElement.Load(path) 'load the xml from file
```

Because this is VB you can use a literal to test with.  I did my best to fix the XML

```
    Dim xe As XElement

    xe = <title>TOSSICOLOGIA D'ABUSO
            <component>
                 <section>
                     <code code="31011" codeSystemName="Codifica Interna Laboratorio" displayName="Etanolo (urine)"></code>
                     <text>
                         <table>
                             <thead>
                                 <tr>
                                     <th>Esame</th>
                                     <th>Esito</th>
                                     <th>Abnormal Flag</th>
                                     <th>Unita di misura</th>
                                     <th>Range di riferimento</th>
                                     <th>Metodo</th>
                                 </tr>
                             </thead>
                             <tbody>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>Etanolo (urine)</td>
                                     <td>&lt; 0,01 g/l</td>
                                     <td></td>
                                     <td></td>
                                     <td>fino a 0,35</td>
                                     <td/>
                                 </tr>
                             </tbody>
                         </table>
                         <footnote></footnote>
                         <paragraph></paragraph>
                     </text>
                 </section>
             </component>
             <section>
                 <code code="32000" codeSystemName="Codifica Interna Laboratorio" displayName="Creatininuria"></code>
                 <text>
                     <table>
                         <thead>
                             <tr>
                                 <th>Esame</th>
                                 <th>Esito</th>
                                 <th>Abnormal Flag</th>
                                 <th>Unita di misura</th>
                                 <th>Range di riferimento</th>
                                 <th>Metodo</th>
                             </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>Creatininuria</td>
                                 <td>193.0</td>
                                 <td></td>
                                 <td>mg/dL</td>
                                 <td>fino a 20: campione non idoneo
                                        (non utilizzabile ai fini medico legali)
                                        20 - 40: campione dubbio
                                        sup. a 40: campione idoneo
                                    </td>
                                 <td/>
                             </tr>
                         </tbody>
                     </table>
                 </text>
             </section>
         </title>
```

Next find one of the tables.  I will use the code node to do that

```
    Dim sectn As XElement = (From el In xe...<code> Where el.@code = "32000" Select el Take 1).FirstOrDefault

    If sectn IsNot Nothing Then 'did we get a code
        'yes
        sectn = sectn.Parent 'the section
        '
    End If
```

Just some ideas.  Hope it helps.
Once we have a section we can iterate the rows in the body

```
    If sectn IsNot Nothing Then 'did we get a section
        'yes
        For Each tr As XElement In sectn...<table>.<tbody>.<tr>
            For Each td As XElement In tr.<td>
                Debug.WriteLine(td.Value)
            Next
        Next
        '
    End If
```

Take a look at the following link

[LINQ to XML link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/overview-of-linq-to-xml)

Comment: thank you.. so much.. i will try.. as for xml it come from hospital as it is .but i will try to fix. thank you @dbasnett

Comment: i have a question please can you write an email at shkelzentarja@gmail.com  . the question is where is the diff between the path vs xe ... should i put the same path, or what??

Comment: No emails sorry.  I tried to fix the post so it was clearer about testing and production.